# What are these Dark Faces on Mesh?

Tags: sculpting

I was in edit mode on a sculpt & ran into an issue where many faces turned dark. Only happens in Sculpting mode. Object, Edit, & Render mode are all fine. It doesn't seem like a normals issue, since I have back faces off.

The issue disappears & resolves itself on it's own if I enable Dynamic Topology & draw (warning that it discarded data).

Things I checked:

- Normals are all correct. Flipping the affected faces makes it worse, & **Recalculate Outside** changes nothing.
- **Merge vertices by distance** made no noticeable change.
- I have not created any materials. I'm only in shading view.
- Masking is already off (`Alt` `M` I think).
- Object Data > Geometry Data shows I dont have custom split data. Toggling it on & off does nothing.

I'm not satisfied forgetting about it, since it took me like a day to resolve by accident.
Was this a bug? or some "feature" to sculpting mode that got cleared when I used Dyntopo?

Blender: **2.90.0**

--

[image: Dark Spots]

Comment: **Update**: So we've loaded it up in Blender 2.8 and the dark faces didn't appear. We think it is just a bug in **2.90.0**.